# I'm unable to understand the question, can someone explain it?

Tags: python

Product of single digits

> Given a positive integer N, check whether it can be represented as a
> product of single digit numbers.
>
> Input Format: Single Integer input.
>
> Output Format: Output displays Yes if condition satisfies else prints
> No.

```
Example Input:
14

Output:
Yes

Example Input:
13

Output:
No
```

Comment: What part of the question you have difficulty to understand? That said, as formulated right now this question is not suitable for SO. Please, take [tour] and check [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm unable to understand the main logic i.e in the example how 14 is considered as 'Yes' and 13 as 'No'

Comment: 14 is a product of 2 * 7, there aren't any combinations of single digit numbers that can make 13

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question gives you a digit N.

You should find out if the number N can be calculated by multiplying two single digit numbers.

For Example:

---

- N = 14
- can be a product of 7*2
- Output = Yes

Comment: 64 would also be a product of single digit numbers but your answer doesn't cover that, This isn't a question suitable to [so] regardless, possibly [maths.se]